# Electrically controlled switch for pH-meter calibration

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, analog-switch

I need to implement a very low voltage drop switch controlled by a microcontroller. I need it to connect (short) two nodes in my circuit for calibration purposes. One node is the input of an opamp (very high input impedance) and the other is the output of another opamp.

I thought about using a simple bjt, but it seems that its Vce drop is too high for my project. So I thought about other solutions like MOSFETs, but I don't know which one is more suitable for this goal.

The lower the voltage drop, the better. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Given that the input impedance is very high, why are you worried about the switch impedance being low?  Either way, a MOSFET could be a good solution.  If you can give a little more information about the application it might be possible to get some more specific advice.

Comment: @Frog I'm developing a pH module. I updated the post with the circuit I was thinking of building.

Comment: @Andrea could you put a number on "very low", please? It's really, even with the schematic, not clear to me what you need to do; not a chemist, but I've never seen anyone needing to short the pH sensor for any reason; could you elaborate on what it is that you need to achieve by shorting?

Comment: @MarcusMüller sure, pH is a value between 0-14, with 7 neutral solution. I need to obtain 2.5V (half the OPAMP range) which means pH = 7 when pH+ is equal to pH-. In order to do this, it is important to short pH+ with pH- and adjust the potentiometer in the first OPAMP. This operation is need to compesate for possible offsets and it is usually done manually (with a little jumper), but I would like to implement it via software. I would like to obtain the same result as a short with a jumper, few mV of voltage drop is torrelable for me.

Comment: But wait, wouldn't it be better if the opamp self-nulled? or does the offset happen somewhere else? (also, what you said sadly did not put a number on "very low" :( )

Comment: Are you sure U3.2 is wired correctly? It looks like it's trying to be a buffer, except + and - are reversed.

Comment: @DanielChisholm you are right! It was my mistake, thank you for finding out.

Comment: @Andrea, there are several open things about your question: When switch is open, who is driving PH+? It is critical to know this because when you short the switch, how do you ensure that PH+ is equal to PH-? When switch is OFF, what is the voltage on PH+ and PH- if PH+ is being driven by some other circuit as well? If PH+ is lower than PH- when the switch is OPEN, there will be leakage through the diode in the switch. Have you thought about it?

Comment: @sai it would be a pH sensor, i.e., essentially a galvanic cell formed by the two electrodes of different materials in the probe, and the liquid the probe is immersed into.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I've never worked with a Galvanic cell but I am guessing that the switch resistance needs to be way lower than the internal resistance of the cell to ensure that we can ensure PH+ = PH- when the switch is ON else, we need to add a series switch and cut-off PH+; in which case, the switch resistance is not important.

Comment: @sai Galvanic cell = battery :) I'm sure you've used one before. Imagine a pH sensor simply being a very low voltage, very low current, i.e., high internal resista<nce, battery.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, got it. I was looking for the internal resistance number. If it is very high compared to the switch ON resistance, then, no issue. Also, if the voltage is only a few mVs then, my other concern is also taken care of. I hope by very low voltage you mean a few mVs.

Comment: High internal resistance means on the order of 10^9 ohms. This means that the off-state characteristics of your switch transistor will be much more important than the on-state characteristics. The short-circuit current available from the probe is about 1 nA. Therefore, the probe current must be no more than a few pA in order to preserve accuracy. But the leakage current of a BSS138 is on the order of 100s of nA. This would effectively be a short circuit across the probe even when the transistor is "off".

Comment: @DaveTweed good point , I hadn’t  considered that. So I do not have to care about on resistance, but only about very high off resistance

Comment: @DaveTweed Surface leakage on a PCB would be a concern as well if we're talking picoamps. You'll probably need to use isolation slots and guard rings, and be very thorough when cleaning off flux residue.

Comment: the schematic makes no sense ... pH- is permanently shorted to GND at U8

Comment: @jsotola U8 is a BNC and yes, pH- is connected to BNC’s GND. I don’t get what the problem is.

Comment: it removes U3.2 from the circuit

Comment: @jsotola but U8 is not connected to ground.

Comment: To clarify, I believe that pH- is connected to the screen of the BNC which is marked as GND on the connector schematic but is not in fact connected to ground.

Comment: @Dave Tweed good point about off-state leakage, but leakage figures are often measured with a few bolts across the device, so at mV levels one might hope for a much lower leakage, although granted such figures may not appear on the datasheet

Comment: On another matter, a 2.5V zener isn’t a great voltage reference, they aren’t that precise and the temperature coefficient will be significant.  You might be better off using a precision voltage reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pH probe can be many hundreds of MΩ source impedance.

A relay is one way to get such high 'off' resistance, for example a reed relay. Typical spec is \$10^{10}\Omega\$ which may not be good enough, however some manufacturers make product that is guaranteed to  \$10^{14}\Omega\$. For example, [here](https://4a30d8fd18dae1bf393d-df49f4cedb726ad03ad145d2e3d346bd.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/datasheets/32/3212001051e.pdf) is one that is guaranteed 1TΩ minimum. On resistance is <0.15Ω.

If you choose to use a relay, add enough external resistance to ensure the peak current through the contact is relatively low (don't make it directly discharge a capacitor, for example). If you are controlling the relay in firmware, a few operations before holding it on wouldn't hurt.

BTW, PCB conditions, including flux and cleaning, can have very significant effects when the source resistances are high, even at the 100MΩ to 1GΩ range. Most PCBs are not required to be very low leakage so other things are optimized.

Answer (score 2):

A MOSFET would be a good solution.  The BSS138 you’ve proposed has a drain-to-source resistance of a few ohms when 5-10V is applied to the gate.  It’s not hard to find FETs with much lower resistance values if you need.  The main thing you’ll need to look at is driving the gate appropriately; if you can ensure it’s at or near 0V in normal operation then it will be effectively open circuit.  For calibration you’ll want to pull the gate up high enough to ensure that the FET is switched on fully.  If you know that the source and drain will be at more or less 2.5V under these conditions then the job is a little easier and you can find a FET with a suitably low threshold voltage so that it conducts amply with Vgs=2.5V.  If the drain voltage could be higher then 2.5V then you may need a higher voltage rail (12 or 15V) that you can pull the gate up to.

Comment: Note that a FET threshold voltage is where it starts to conduct (perhaps micro amps), you’ll need to look at the datasheet to see what gate voltage is needed to achieve the desired drain-source resistance.

Comment: Also note that FETs have a ‘body diode’ which will start to conduct if there’s a few hundred millivolts across it.  If that’s likely to be a problem then you could use two FETs in series so that one diode is always reverse-biased and therefore won’t conduct when the FET is switched off.  When switched on the FETs will conduct in either direction, drain to source or source to drain.

Comment: I do have doubts; you're arguing with voltage vs current of the proposed capacitor, but the currents here will be incredibly low. As @DaveTweed mentions under the question, the off-characteristics of the MOSFET would be more relevant.